# Should questions with an open bounty be flagged to moderators' attention for deletion, if needed?

Tags: discussion, flags, bounties

I had once a question with an open bounty and that time I didn't know about this site. Once that bounty started, I got the problem solution in two or three days still I was waiting for answers from other users so that I could accept one of them and offered the bounty (and may be they have more a concrete solution than mine).

I kept waiting for some days but no answers were posted by other users. Therefore, I flagged that post to moderator's attention requesting to delete that post. The flag was disputed but the question was indeed deleted and I got the offered reputation back.

Is this a legal reason to flag such posts to moderators' attention for deletion? (I just want to know, if it's as per rules).

Comment: Did you ask for deletion of your own question after you got a good answer?  If so it looks like a misuse of the bounty system.

Comment: No, if the question doesn't get any answers (for own posts) and I don't plan to do so but that time I was very to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that deleted questions on Stack Overflow could question ban your account, which means you could not ask questions anymore.

As for asking to delete your own question to get back the reputation you put in the bounty, that is not what I would suggest to do. Moderators have deleted your question, but that doesn't mean they will do it again in the future. If you keep doing it, that could be the sign you need to be more careful on which questions you offer the bounty, considering that bounties are the last resource.

Even if you didn't have any answer, your question has been placed in a list where it has been more visible to the users.

Comment: "*As for asking to delete your own question to get back the reputation*". No, it was because I didn't know about it that time. Thanks for the concrete answer.